# Filtering ObservableList with CheckBox in JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx, observablelist

I'm building a log reader with JavaFX as a side project and have gotten to a dead end when trying to implement filtering on the `TableView`.

What I have is a few `CheckBox`es (LHS of the picture) that will basically act as the filters for what the `TableView` will display:

[image: Window]

Once the `Submit` button is clicked, a background thread is opened to read the and parse the files. Once the operation terminates, the result of each log read is inserted into the global `ObservableList<Log>`:

```
 public class Test_Filters extends Application {...

 private ObservableList<LogTest> logs = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

...}
```

What I'm having trouble with is how to deal with:

1. A situation where more than one filter `CheckBox` is checked.
2. A situation where the `CheckBox` is unchecked.

For 1., I was wondering what's the best way to deal with this. Let's say I have `x` filters selected. This would mean that I have to basically filter out `x` values from the `ObservaleList`:

```
logTable.setItems(logTable.getItems().filtered(log -> !log.getSource().equals(checkBox.getText())));
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use JavaFX's [`FilteredList`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/collections/transformation/FilteredList.html), which accepts a [`Predicate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Predicate.html). You can update the predicate on each filter, combining them as you want.

```
 FilteredList<LogTest> items = new FilteredList<>(originalItems);
 tableView.setItems(items);

 ... on update of filter UI items
 Predicate<LogTest> containsFoo = i -> i.getName().contains("foo");
 Predicate<LogTest> isSevere = i -> i.getLevel() == Level.SEVERE;
 Predicate<LogTest> filter = containsFoo.or(isSevere);

 items.setPredicate(filter);
```

If you want to show all records again simply set the predicate to `null`:

```
 items.setPredicate(null);
```

Using the `FilteredList` you don't need to re-read the log records, as the filter is applied immediately on the existing items.